# Can't move MS Access file after opening JDBC connection on it

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-batch, ucanaccess

I've got a Spring Batch job that is reading a specified Access database file.  I'm using `uncanaccess` JDBC library to do so.  Once the job exits, whether the job completes successfully or not, I need to have my application move the access file to another folder.  Currently I'm getting a `java.nio.file.FileSystemException` that states it can't be moved because it's used by another process.  I'm assuming the other process is due to the fact that the JDBC connection was opened.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mycompany.weeklyimport.FileException: Failed to move file [C:\temp\hold\temp.mdb] to [C:\temp\error\temp.mdb]
    at com.mycompany.weeklyimport.WeeklyImportApplication.moveFile(WeeklyImportApplication.java:365)
    at com.mycompany.weeklyimport.WeeklyImportApplication.main(WeeklyImportApplication.java:91)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\temp\hold\temp.mdb -> C:\temp\error\temp.mdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at com.mycompany.weeklyimport.WeeklyImportApplication.moveFile(WeeklyImportApplication.java:363)
    ... 1 more
```

Here's my main program (that runs the Spring job via Spring Boot):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Slf4j
public class WeeklyImportApplication extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    ...
    private static String inputFile;
    private static boolean exceptionEncountered = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        handleArguments(args);

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(WeeklyImportApplication.class).listeners(new CustomLoggingConfigurationApplicationListener(logConfigurer)).run(args);

        if (exceptionEncountered) {
            moveFile("error");
        } else {
            moveFile("complete");
        }

        finished();
    }

    private static void moveFile(String folderName) {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        File newPath = new File(file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath() + File.separator + folderName);

        if (!newPath.exists()) {
            if (!newPath.mkdirs()) {
                throw new FileException("Failed to create folder [" + newPath.getPath() + "]");
            }
        }

        File newFile = new File(newPath.getPath() + File.separator + file.getName());

        try {
            Files.move(file.toPath(), newFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FileException("Failed to move file [" + file.getPath() + "] to [" + newFile.getPath() + "]", ex);
        }
    }

    ...
```

My datasource configuration.  I'm assigning to a static variable as well to attempt to close the connection once Spring exits.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    public static SingleConnectionDataSource legacyDataSource;

    @Bean(name = "importDataSource")
    public DataSource importDataSource() {
        SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.importDriver.trim());
        dataSource.setSuppressClose(true);
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + WeeklyImportApplication.getInputFile());

        return dataSource;
    }

    ...
```

I've tried the following:

```
    DataSourceConfiguration.legacyDataSource.getConnection().close();
    DataSourceConfiguration.legacyDataSource.destroy();
    DataSourceConfiguration.legacyDataSource = null;
```

Somehow, something still has a lock on that file.  Has anyone encountered anything like this or have any ideas on how to force the true close of the file read?

**SOLVED**

jamadei's answer below helped me get to this solution.  Relevant solution code:

```
@Bean(name = "importDataSource")
public DataSource importDataSource() {
    SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.importDriver.trim());
    dataSource.setSuppressClose(true);
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + WeeklyImportApplication.getInputFile() + ";SingleConnection=true");

    importDataSource = dataSource;

    return dataSource;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    handleArguments(args);

    new SpringApplicationBuilder(WeeklyImportApplication.class).listeners(new CustomLoggingConfigurationApplicationListener(logConfigurer)).run(args);

    DataSourceConfiguration.importDataSource.setSuppressClose(false);
    DataSourceConfiguration.importDataSource.destroy();

    if (exceptionEncountered) {
        moveFile("error");
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        moveFile("complete");
    }

    finished();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just a Spring matter but a UCanAccess optimisation/cache side effect.
What you have done seems to be good, but it's not enough.
The use of the SingleConnection=true parameter in the jdbc url should solve the issue.

Comment: This helped me get to the solution.  I had inadvertently posted the wrong datasource in the question above, so I edited and corrected.  One other thing I was doing was I had the `setSuppressClose` option on the `DataSource` set to true.  Once I set removed that statement AND applied your suggested parameter to the URL then I was able to move the file within my application.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a followup, once I took my exception out that I was throwing for testing purposes, I encountered an exception thrown from Spring due to the datasource being closed on a subsequent step that also needed that datasource, so I had to set suppress close back to true.  I got around this at the shutdown of my application by setting it back to false and then calling `destroy()` on the datasource, prior to doing the file move.